# A substitute for doc.evaluate

Tags: javascript, firefox, xpath

Is there any shorter expression to get DOM nods via XPath, more concise from following command that need a lot of variables.

```
doc.evaluate(xpath, doc, nsResolver, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know Firefox only supports the DOM Level 3 XPath API, part of which the `evaluate` function is. If you want something shorter then you need to roll your own (or find a library which does it for you) or you need to use a different browser, for instance with Opera you can do e.g. `node.selectSingleNode(path [,nsResolver])` to select a single node, with `node.selectNodes(path [, nsResolver])` you can select a DOM NodeList of nodes. Within MSXML's XML DOM implementation you use with IE you also have `selectSingleNode` and `selectNodes` function although namespace handing there is different from the Opera implementation as with MSXML you need to use `document.setProperty('SelectionNamespaces', 'xmlns:pf1="http://example.com/ns1" xmlns:pf2="http://example.com/ns2"')`.

Comment: Actually I want  test some xpath address in console of firebug, so I can not use other libraries. Some plug-ins dp xpath evaluation right now.